# What is $r^n$ where $r \subseteq P(\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N})$ and $n$ is natural number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got a set theory problem in which I examine the following function:

$$\rho : P(\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}) \rightarrow P(\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N})$$

$$\rho(r) = \bigcup\{ r^{2^n}|n\in\Bbb{N}\}$$

I've got a problem with $r^{2^n}$. I mean, what does it actually mean to "factor" a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: What does $P(.)$ mean?

Comment: P(A) ought to be the set of all subsets of A

Comment: P denotes the power set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of two relations $R,S$ is $R S = \{(a,c) : \exists b (a,b) \in R \wedge (b,c) \in S\}$. It is now clear what $R^n$ is. (In order to avoid confusions, one should better write $R \circ S$ and $R^{\circ n}$.)